# Validate Radio Button Groups Without jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button, validation

I am trying to validate a form on each slide before sliding to the next set of questions.

All seems to be ok except for the radio buttons. I am trying to add a class of 'error-focus' to a group of buttons if a button is not checked and if the answer is checked it will do nothing apart from return $error = false;

Here is the form http://www.foresightaus.com.au/form/

```
    $nextBtn.click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var newIndex = 0,
            currentSlide = $slide.eq(currentIndex),
            $text = currentSlide.find($('li input[type="text"]')),
            $email = currentSlide.find($('#yourEmail')),
            $radio = currentSlide.find($('li.radio-btns')),
            formFields = currentSlide.find("input:text, li.radio-btns"),
            $error = true;  

        formFields.removeClass("error-focus");  

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //-- Validate Text Fields

        $text.each(function(){

            if($(this).val()==""){

                //errorMessage("Please Enter Your Name");
                $(this).focus().addClass("error-focus");
                $error = true;

            }else{

                $error = false;

            }

        }); // end text each

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //-- Validate Email Fields

        if($email.val()==""){

            //errorMessage("Please Enter Your Email Address");
            $(this).focus().addClass("error-focus");
            $error = true;

        }else if(!isValidEmail($email.val())){

            //errorMessage("Please Enter a Correct Email Address");
            $(this).focus().addClass("error-focus");
            $error = true;

        }else{

                $error = false;

        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //-- Validate Radio Fields

        $radio.each(function(){

            if (!$(this).find(':checked')) {

               $(this).addClass("error-focus");
               $error = true;

            }

            else {

              $error = false;

            }

        }); // end radio each

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------

        if($error = false){

            if(currentIndex<lastIndex){
                newIndex = currentIndex+1;
            }

            slideToImage(newIndex); 

        }       

    });

    function isValidEmail(email) {
        var emailRx = /^[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+$/;
        return  emailRx.test(email);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a div around each radio group, and if one of the radio buttons isn't checked, you should just give the div the red border that you're giving the other fields. An example:

**HTML**

```
<form>
<div id="group-1-wrapper">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
</div>
</form>
```

**js**:

```
if(error) // your handling
$("#group-1-wrapper").addClass("error-focus");
```

Comment: Sorry my question may not have been clear, the adding of the class is not really my problem it is more that if say on question one you have checked the "male" option when you click send the "female" one will still have add the class even though it is in the same group

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones So wrap the groups of radio buttons in a `div` tag, and then check if at least one is checked *from within* the div tag (essentially grouping them)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few different ways but this worked for me. 
@Evan thanks for pointing me in the right direction

```
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //-- Validate Radio Fields

        $radio.each(function(){

            if ($(this).find('input:radio').is(':checked')) {

                $error = false;

            }else{

                $(this).addClass("error-focus");
                $error = true;

            }

        }); // end radio each
```